# Laravel sends insecure url in default mail templates

Tags: laravel

My Laravel Application sends insecure url that is with "http" in default mail templates. While I have configured APP_URL with https in .env file.

If I force route to use https then it sends mail with https link, but the problem is when I click on "Verify email address", then it shows "403 | Invalid signature."

Can anyone help me sort out this problem.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892356/laravel-5-7-signed-route-returns-403-invalid-signature