# Remove query parameters for signed url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-8

When a user clicks on the link in my mail it will be forwarded to the [signed url](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#signed-urls) I created. The controller method looks like this:

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    //Remove default sendinblue query parameters
    foreach (array_keys($request->all()) as $key) {
        if (! in_array($key, ['expires', 'signature'])) {
            $request->server->remove($key);
        }
    }

    if (! $request->hasValidSignature()) {
        return redirect()->to('https://snuffelbox.nl');
    }

    //Passes
}
```

The problem is that my mail provider is always adding query parameters like `utm_source` etc, making the request invalid. So that's why I'm stripping all query parameters except for `expires` and `signature`.

In the [->hasValidSignature()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a69d9d61f488b2d58ffb72410c5863b271d67086/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L404) method Laravel is using this for getting the url:

```
$request->server->get('QUERY_STRING')
```

But no matter what I try I can't strip the query parameters from the url.

This is not working:

```
$request->server->remove($key);
```

And neither is this:

```
$request->request->remove($key);
```

Any idea how I can fix this problem?

**--EDIT--**

Url from mail:

https://link.com/2/SlqC4BRd?signature=00be549770a7c5aa5624c5941ce9dc7eaf583d27aa1ebb61a0dbcb96f0f80191&utm_source=mail

What it should become (then it's valid, already tested that):

https://link.com/2/SlqC4BRd?signature=00be549770a7c5aa5624c5941ce9dc7eaf583d27aa1ebb61a0dbcb96f0f80191

Signed route is created like this:

```
$link = URL::signedRoute('inertia.upsell.show', [$group->id, $order->token]);
```

Comment: Could you add an example url with the corresponding route?

Comment: Could you try using `$request->query->remove('utm_source');` instead of `$request->server->remove($key);`?

Comment: @MaartenDev not working unfortunately.

Comment: Could you add some debug points in `UrlGenerator.php` where the url is validated? You can checkout this answer for tips: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54034735/6310593

Comment: I don't think the additional query params would make the url invalid. What Laravel try to validate should only be the `signature` param. Have you verified if this is the case?

Comment: If nothing is working you can try this dumb idea of getting the URL and then redirecting again with only the ``expires `` parameter.

Comment: can you try this ``if (! $request->hasValidSignature(false) )`` ?

Comment: If I remove all query parameters except `signature` it's working, so additional query params are not allowed. Also laravel checks if there are other query parameters https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a69d9d61f488b2d58ffb72410c5863b271d67086/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L408

Comment: @OMIShah not working.

Comment: I guess laravel uses `$request->server->get('QUERY_STRING')` for validation. So Try editing the parameter like: `$customQueryString = http_build_query($request->only(['param1', 'param2' ..]));
$request->server->set('QUERY_STRING', $customQueryString);`

Comment: @iamab.in thanks! That's working!

Answer (score 1):

In [Laravel 9.x](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/urls#validating-signed-route-requests), you can use `hasValidSignatureWhileIgnoring` method to ignore specific parameters:

```
if (! $request->hasValidSignatureWhileIgnoring(['utm_source', 'other_params'])) {
    abort(401);
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation to your code - it is very hard to understand something when it isn't explained.